# How to overcome from ---Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to character

Tags: algorithm, matlab, encryption

Please can any one tell me how to overcome the warning "Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to character".
This warning is getting when implementing RSA algorithm by using MATLAB.The below RSA algorithm can run when we take two prime numbers P and Q having bit length up to 14 bits each,  but for more than 14 bits length prime number that warning is coming.(example: p=16411 and q=16417)

plz help me out from this Warning.

**Below is the result::::**

```
The value of (n) is: 269419387
The public key (e) is: 7
The value of (Phi) is: 269386560
The private key (d)is: 115451383

Enter the message: hi
ASCII Code of the entered Message:
   104   105

Cipher Text of the entered Message:
   127892400   109597748


Decrypted ASCII of Message:
   117366160    13037262

Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to character.

Decrypted Message is:
```

**The RSA algorithm is:**

```
function a = d2b(d)
i=1;
a=zeros(1,65535);
while d >= 2
    r=rem(d,2);
    if r==1
        a(i)=1;
    else
        a(i)=0;
    end
    i=i+1;
    d=floor(d/2);
end
if d == 2
    a(i) = 0;
else
    a(i) = 1;
end
x=[a(16) a(15) a(14) a(13) a(12) a(11) a(10) a(9) a(8) a(7) a(6) a(5)]
init.m   
%For Initialization
function [Pk,Phi,d,e] = init(p,q)
clc;
disp('Initializing:');
Pk=p*q;
Phi=(p-1)*(q-1);
%For Calculating the value of e
x=2;e=1;
while x > 1
    e=e+1;
    x=gcd(Phi,e);
end
%For Calculating the value of d
i=1;
r=1;
while r > 0
    k=(Phi*i)+1;
    r=rem(k,e);
    i=i+1;
end
d=k/e;
clc;
disp(['The value of (N) is: ' num2str(Pk)]);
disp(['The public key (e) is: ' num2str(e)]);
disp(['The value of (Phi) is: ' num2str(Phi)]);
disp(['The private key (d)is: ' num2str(d)]);
crypto.m     
%For Cryptography Key Generation
function mc = crypto(M,N,e)
e=d2b(e);
k = 65535;
c  = M;
cf = 1;
cf=mod(c*cf,N);
for i=k-1:-1:1
    c = mod(c*c,N);
    j=k-i+1;
     if e(j)==1
         cf=mod(c*cf,N);
     end
end
mc=cf;
rsa.m  
%for RSA Algorithm
clc;
disp('Implementation of RSA Algorithm');
clear all; 
close all;
p = input('\nEnter value of p: ');
q = input('\nEnter value of q: ');
[Pk,Phi,d,e] = init(p,q);
M = input('\nEnter message: ','s');
x=length(M);
c=0;
for j= 1:x
    for i=0:122
        if strcmp(M(j),char(i))
            c(j)=i;
        end
    end
end
disp('ASCII Code of the entered Message:');
disp(c); 
% For Encryption
for j= 1:x
   cipher(j)= crypto(c(j),Pk,e); 
end
disp('Cipher Text of the entered Message:');
disp(cipher);
% For Decryption
for j= 1:x
   message(j)= crypto(cipher(j),Pk,d); 
end
disp('Decrypted ASCII of Message:');
disp(message);
disp(['Decrypted Message is: ' message]);
```

THANKING YOU

Comment: Insert `warning('off','MATLAB:nonIntegerTruncatedInConversionToChar');` before `disp('Decrypted ASCII of Message:');`. See [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html) for more information and alternative solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion @ user1391279 , yes program is free from warning,but program is not decrypting the original message for higher bit length prime numbers.....please  help me if any idea...